# what's the purpose of '気でいたんだ' in this sentence

Tags: grammar

The full sentence is:

> 何{なに}もかも手{て}にした気{き}でいたんだ

For now I think 何もかも手にした comes from 何もかも手にする 'to obtain just about everything / almost everything' but I can't understand  the purpose of the rest and how it changes the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: why "just about" "almost"? 　「何もかも」"anything and everything"

Comment: 'Anything and everything' was one of the two definitions that [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%95%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82) provided. The other one was 'Just about everything' which did more sense in the context.

Comment: hee.. 何もかも means すべて, 全部... So "just about everything" "almost everything" can also mean すべて?

Comment: So It would correct to say that 何もかも手にした means "I've got everything"? if that's correct how does 気でいたんだ change the sentence's meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

～～した気でいる means "to (keep/stay) think/imagine/feel(ing) that one did~~". (≂ ～～したつもりでいる)  (cf. 「～～した気になる」 "to think/feel/imagine one did~~", 「～～のつもりでいる」 "to fancy oneself as~~")

何もかも手にする means "to gain/obtain (anything and) everything".

So 何もかも手にした気でいたんだ literally means "I thought/imagined that I had obtained everything."